# iPad Simulator showing iPhone build

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode7, simulator

In XCode 7.2:

I ran into an issue getting my app to simulate the iPad version and wanted to post the solution for any other beginners who run into this problem. The solution:

Select your top level project file in the leftmost file hierarchy -> Targets -> [yourapp] -> General -> Deployment Info -> Devices -> set to 'Universal'

Mine had been set to iPhone.

Comment: iphone apps also run in ipad at iphone resolution.

Comment: indeed, but my goal was to create a native iPad build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your top level project file in the leftmost file hierarchy -> Targets -> [yourapp] -> General -> Deployment Info -> Devices -> set to 'Universal'